# Go to line/loop switch statement?

Tags: c#, console-application

Im not even sure what to call what I want to do...
Basically I have a selection screen and use a switch statement instead of an if/else, in the default portion of the switch statement I want to ask a confirm to quit...
Basically

```
switch(input)
{
    default:
        Console.WriteLine("Are you sure?")
        var confirm = Console.ReadLine();

        switch (confirm)
        {
            case "y":
                //quit
            case "n":
                break;
            default:
                // GO BACK TO Console.WriteLine();
                break;
        }

        break;
}
```

Basically I need to go back to the Console.WriteLine(); part, but Im not sure what the most efficient method is to do that?

Comment: what you want is a while loop... `initialize with 'no'; while (user says no) { ask for confirmation; if user says yes break loop; }`

Answer (score 0):

1. The first switch statement is totally useless as there is only a default.
2. I do not know what means `// GO BACK TO Console.WriteLine();` (WHERE???!) but I guess you want to do something like this:

   ```
    boolean toExit = false;
    while (!toExit) {
    // And for what is the input??
    string input = Console.ReadLine();

    Console.WriteLine("Are you sure?")
    var confirm = Console.ReadLine();

    switch (confirm)
    {
        case "y":
            toExit = true;
            break;
        case "n":
            break;
        default:
            // GO BACK TO Console.WriteLine();
           // SO, WHERE?
            break;
    }
   ```

}

Comment: 1. Sorry, I didnt write out my 15 case switch statement to you, its useless info and a waste of time for someone to even read it.
2. Its literally right there : line 7 in the whole post, line 4 in the code.

Answer (score 0):

If I want some interactivity in console application I usually create a bunch of Control classes (similar to WinForms, with a bunch of various feature like color/align/etc). To prompt console dialog for simple answer Yes/No, you could use just simple method:

```
public static bool PromptYesNoDialog(string question)
{
    Console.WriteLine(question);
    while(true)
    {
        var answer = Console.ReadLine().Trim().ToLower();
        if(answer.Equals("y") || answer.Equals("yes"))
            return true;
        if(answer.Equals("n") || answer.Equals("no"))
            return false;
        Console.WriteLine("Answer should be 'y' or 'n'.");
    }
}
```

Then use it:

```
   //doing work, and encountered problem which only user can solve
   if(PromptYesNoDialog("Do you wanna play?"))
   {
      //play
   }
   else
   {
      //not play
   }
```